# Moving undecorated window by clicking on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, border, panel

Is there a possibility to move window by clicking on one of the panels in the window when that window is undecorated?

I have a main panel with matte border 40 pixels size, and few panels with controls inside, and I would like to move the window when clicking on that border. Is that possible?

Comment: There is no need to include Java in the title if it is a tag.

Answer (score 38):

You can place another panel over the **panel with the border**, leaving the border visible.Use the following code to move your window.

```
public class MotionPanel extends JPanel{
    private Point initialClick;
    private JFrame parent;

    public MotionPanel(final JFrame parent){
    this.parent = parent;

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            initialClick = e.getPoint();
            getComponentAt(initialClick);
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            // get location of Window
            int thisX = parent.getLocation().x;
            int thisY = parent.getLocation().y;

            // Determine how much the mouse moved since the initial click
            int xMoved = e.getX() - initialClick.x;
            int yMoved = e.getY() - initialClick.y;

            // Move window to this position
            int X = thisX + xMoved;
            int Y = thisY + yMoved;
            parent.setLocation(X, Y);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I've been working with this code for a while now to make a custom titlebar for undecorated windows. 
P.S.:You can generalize this example by extending JComponent instead of JPanel.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

> I have a main panel with matte border 40 pixels size, and few panels with controls inside, and I would like to move the window when clicking on that border

I think that [ComponetMover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) by @camickr is right class for you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible. You need a MouseListener to listen on mouse events. you start moving on mousedown and stop moving on mouseup. Then you simply translate the window position by the same amount the mouse translates during that phase (calculate the delta bewteen old mouse position and new mouse position and add that to the frames position). You should be able to do this with a mouse listener fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution from my project. Here is my undecorated JDialog class.

```
public class TimerDialog extends JDialog {
// some fields here
private Point mouseClickPoint; // Will reference to the last pressing (not clicking) position

private TimerDialog() {
    initComponents();
    addEventsForDragging();
}

private void addEventsForDragging() {
    // Here is the code does moving
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseClickPoint = e.getPoint(); // update the position
        }

    });
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            Point newPoint = event.getLocationOnScreen();
            newPoint.translate(-mouseClickPoint.x, -mouseClickPoint.y); // Moves the point by given values from its location
            setLocation(newPoint); // set the new location
        }
    });
}

private void initComponents() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    // adding components
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setResizable(false);
    pack();
}
}
```

Comment: I can't figure how but this one works better on my HiDPI screen

Answer (score 0):

```
int xMoved = (thisX + e.getX()) - (thisX + initialClick.x);
```

thisX + -thisX = 0

```
int xMoved = e.getX()-initialClick.x;
```

What i'm using.

```
public class MouseLiestenerX implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{

private theFrame;

public MouseLiestenerX(Frame theFrame){
this.theFrame = theFrame;

}

private Point startClick;

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    int deltaX = e.getX()-startClick.x;
    int deltaY = e.getY()-startClick.y;

    Core.getSp().setLocation(theFrame.getLocation().x+deltaX, theFrame.getLocation().y+deltaY);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    startClick = e.getPoint();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){

}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}
```

}

and in your Frame constructor

```
MouseLiestenerX IMove = new MouseLiestenerX(this);      
addMouseListener(IMove);
addMouseMotionListener(IMove);
```