# How to move undecorated JFrame by holding click on a JPanel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, move

I've been making an undecorated JFrame so far and I was wondering if it's possible to move the undecorated JFrame by holding click on a JPanel.

Here is the source code I'm working on.

```
private static void createFrame()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Frame");
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(500,300);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 2, 500, 50);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(60, 65, 70));
    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

What I want to do is: 
Click and hold my cursor at the JPanel area to be able to move the JFrame.

I did some research and came across to a similar question: [Moving undecorated window by clicking on JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773713/moving-undecorated-window-by-clicking-on-jpanel)

I don't understand how to integrate the code provided (by user Sorter) on my code.

Or are there another solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24476755/2587435

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution provided can easily be integrated into your example.

Just add Sorter's example as a separate class.

Then change

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

to

```
JPanel panel = new MotionPanel(frame);
```

The panel should now be movable.

Comment: Thank you. I made a new .java file for the MotionPanel and I did what you said, now it works like a charm. Thank you very much

Comment: I guess here is where `MotionPanel` was invented. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13171534/1097600

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a class that does this for you.

The class is designed to allow you to move a window on the desktop, or components on a panel.